# What is the problem in random.choice function that it does not provide proper result?

Tags: python, list, numpy, random, seed

Here I am doing simulation experiment by filling pre-defined number of bins with balls which are equal in count. I have defined firstly some number of bins and balls list and num_exp to make experiment that much.

For this reason in second part of code I create balls and empty bins as much as I have defined in list.

In third part of code I fill bins with rule k = 1 which means for every ball one random bins will come and ball will go there (min() function hade been written for k = 2 case where 2 bins will come randomly and ball will go to least occupied one).

The point is I need to do this experiment with pre-defined number of experiments and I add outer loop for that. If you remove outer loop it will work perfectly well but with that it does now provide roper result. I guess it is related with random function but cannot define exactly or solve this problem. I would be grateful if someone help. Thanks in advance.

```
bins_balls = [10,20,30,40,50]
num_exp = 15


balls = []
bins = []
for i in range(len(bins_balls)):
    ball_pack = np.ones(bins_balls[i])
    balls.append(ball_pack)
    bin_lists = [[] for i in range(balls[i].shape[0])]
    bins.append(bin_lists)



bins_new = []
for exp in range(num_exp):
    random.seed(exp+1)
    for pack in range(len(balls)):
        for ball in range(balls[pack].shape[0]):
            selected = random.choices(bins[pack], k = 1) #pick random k number of bins uniformly with replacement
            min(selected, key=len).append(balls[pack][ball]) # place the ball to the least occupied one  
    bins_new.append(bins)
```

Comment: You `random.seed` in the outer loop using different seeds for each experiment, but then immediately seed again in the inner loop, giving the same random seed to all experiments (and all "packs" in those experiments).

Comment: It was there by mistake. I edited the code.

Comment: if you use the part from ''random.seed(exp+1)'' to ''min(selected, key=len).append(balls[pack][ball])'' both included it will work and fill the bins randomly as it is required, when I make it repeats for some num_exp and add one outer loop it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you re-use the same `bins` list-of-lists for each experiment, appending elements to their sublists and then adding the whole thing to the `bins_new`, one reference to the instance for each experiment.

Instead, you should probably (deep-)copy the `bins` before modifying them for the different experiments:

```
import copy

bins_new = []
for exp in range(num_exp):
    random.seed(exp+1)
    bins2 = copy.deepcopy(bins)
    for pack in range(len(balls)):
        for ball in range(balls[pack].shape[0]):
            selected = random.choices(bins2[pack], k = 1)
            min(selected, key=len).append(balls[pack][ball])
    bins_new.append(bins2)
```